# Does Ethers.js log events before the blocks they belong to are mined?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I'm using the following lines to capture all future emissions of the `Triggered` event.

```js
const filter = contract.filters.Triggered(null, null, null);

provider.on(filter, (log) => {
  console.log("event log:\n", log);
}
```

Is the event captured in Ethers before its block is mined or after? I know that the default case for how Web3.js captures events is that it returns the event log before its block is mined, but I'm curious about how Ethers handles events.